# Error pushing Heroku created App to Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, github, ssh

I have created an Empty rails project using RailsInstaller, was able to generate an SSH pair and set my project up on git/github. I then went to get set up on Heroku, gem install and create commands went well. Attempted to git push and received the error below, attempted to ssh to heroku with PuTTY but I'm not even sure that is the right step. I have been following exact instructions from [this book](http://dl.e-book-free.com/2013/07/ruby_on_rails_tutorial_2nd_edition.pdf) to set up this project.

```
C:\Rails_Projects\first_app>heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: C:/Users/Jeff/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Jeff/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done

C:\Rails_Projects\first_app>heroku create --stack cedar
Creating protected-spire-2324... done, stack is cedar
http://protected-spire-2324.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:protected-spire-2324
.git
Git remote heroku added

C:\Rails_Projects\first_app>git push heroku master
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information and thank you.

Comment: This may be out of date, but at a previous job we discovered that some Windows ssh key generators made by default too-short RSA keys which led to quiet rejections of keys.  See, e.g., http://dafis.ucdavis.edu/install/sftp/PuttyGen.cfm for instructions.

Comment: those look to be the same instructions I followed, plus if I am using the same key and it works for GitHub could it still be too short for Heroku?

Comment: If you've gone for a 4K key, that's probably not the problem, then.  (I generally avoid Windows as much as possible and have not used heroku so am not at all sure what the underlying problem is.)

Comment: I generally do as well, unfortunately the new computer is a Lenovo and is extremely unhappy with linux (tons of network issues when installing Kali, Fedora, Mint or Ubuntu). My old computer was a Kali build, miss that OS... Appreciate the attempted help though!